# Unittest check if main called methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a `main` method that looks like this:

```
class Example:
    ...
    def main(self):
        self.one()
        self.two(list)
        self.three(self.four(4))
```

How to check if the calling `main` it calls the following methods inside it?

I have tried:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.ex = example.Example()

def test_two(self):
    # testing method two that has only list.append(int) and returns list
    mock_obj = Mock()
    self.ex.two(mock_obj, 1)
    self.assertEqual(call.append(1),mock_obj.method_calls[0]) # works fine
    mock_obj.method.called # throws False ...why?

def test_main(self):
    with patch('example.Example') as a:
    a.main()
    print(a.mock_calls)  # [call.main()]

...
def test_main(self):
    mock_obj = Mock()
    self.ex.main(mock_obj) # throws TypeError: main() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
    print(mock_obj.method_calls) # expected one, two, three and four method calls
```

Realy need any help to be honest..

Using Python 2.6.6 with unittest and mock modules

Comment: "Using Python 2.6.6" I guess it's time for some upgrades.

Comment: @KlausD. Sadly I cannot upgrade it yet..

Answer (score 0):

With unit-testing you could in principle test if these four functions would actually be called.  And, you could certainly do this by mocking all of them.  However, you would need integration tests later anyway to be sure that the functions were called in the proper order, with the arguments in the proper order, arguments having values in the form expected by the callee, return values being in the expected form etc.

You can check all these things in unit-testing - but this has not much value, because if you have wrong assumptions about one of these points, your wrong assumptions will go into both your code and your unit-tests.  That is, the unit-tests will test exactly against your wrong assumptions and will pass.  Finding out about your wrong assumptions requires an integration test where the real caller and callee are brought together.

Summarized: Your main method is interaction dominated and thus should rather be tested directly by interaction-testing (aka integration-testing) rather than by unit-testing plus subsequent interaction-testing.